# Having some problems with htaccess remove .php and id= and add slash

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have this htaccess and it almost is working, but..

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.loggs\.no [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://loggs.no/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+show(?:\.php)?\?id=([0-9]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ show/%1? [R,L]

RewriteRule ^show/([0-9]+)/?$ show.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]

## hide .php extension snippet
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]

# add a trailing slash    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule . %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]
```

But it doesn't add trailing slashes to all my pages and when I'm clicking on `show/6` and then will go to *e.g.* `Show/3` it goes until `show/show/3`
and I would like to remove `.php` for all my pages too.

Comment: add this just below `<head>` section of your page's HTML: `<base href="/" />`

Comment: Thx @anubhava first problem fixet

Comment: Can i make show.php dynamic so it also rewrites .php from feeds.php or links.php

Comment: You mean you want links as: `/feeds/6` and `/links/6` as well?

Comment: yes and if i make more pages @anubhava

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use these rules in site root .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(loggs\.no)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ https://%1/$1/ [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(show|feeds|links)(?:\.php)?\?id=([0-9]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2/? [R=301,NE,L]

## hide .php extension snippet
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/ [R=301,NE,L]

# add a trailing slash    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule . %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^(show|feeds|links)/([0-9]+)/?$ $1.php?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^(show|feeds|links)/?$ $1.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: its rewrites the feeds.php to /feeds/ but it still sents me to a 404page

Comment: it doesnt work without the id number /feeds/ only with the id /feeds/4/

Comment: now its working, need to test a little before accepting